# merging all columns with numerical values in to a single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
A1   A2  A3......... A10
2    32  41.........  11
12   44  21.........  21
10   3   90.........  80
```

And I am trying to create a pandas data frame with one single column with values of all other columns separated by a single space. The type of this resulting column should be an object. it should look like this:

```
        A
2 32 41.........  11
12 44 21.........  21
10 3  90.........  80
```

I have tried the following code; however, that requires me to convert the datatype for each column to be a string which I do not want to do:

```
df['A1'] + ' ' + df['A2']+ ' ' + df['A3'] + ' ' + df['A4']+......+df['A10'].astype(str)
```

Comment: `that requires me to convert the datatype for each column to be a string which I do not want to do` - so how want join not strings like strings? It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible join numbers like strings without converting to strings in python.

Only is possible create lists:

```
#all columns with A in column name
df['A'] = df.filter(like='A').agg(list, axis=1)
```

---

```
#all columns
df['A'] = df.agg(list, axis=1)
```